# Find an element in RDD Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Is there an efficient way to find a specific element in `RDD` and then remove it ?

For example:

```scala
sc.parallelize(Array(Array(4,2,6),Array(2,5),Array(1, 2, 3), Array(1, 2, 6)))
```

Find the  Array(1,2,3) in `RDD` with the specific values and remove it ,is that possible
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand, you should explain more.

Comment: I have corrected my question. More general, i want to find an element and remove from the rdd

Comment: technically RDDs are immutable so you cannot remove anything from them. You can create a new RDD based on the one you have without your element. @AlbertoBonsanto answered this already (unless you want to remove only the first occurrence?)

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to remove one row of the RDD, then you should use the method `filter` from `RDD`s, the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) states:

> Return a new RDD containing only the elements that satisfy a predicate.

This means that all records are compared using the expression inside the lambda and if they satisfy the condition they are kept otherwise they are removed from the new `RDD`.

```
val xrdd = sc.parallelize(Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(1, 2, 6)))
xrdd.filter(_.sameElements(Array(1, 2, 3))).take(3)
// Array(Array(1, 2, 6))
```

Comment: It might not be the first row.Let's say we have thousand records and i want to find the specific array and remove it.

Comment: @Nick You need a better example... I still don't get what you want

Comment: @Nick the code he posted doesn't filter out the first row, it checks *every* element and filters out the ones that are equal to `Array(1,2,3)`